# Rename branch name in Map power bi

Tags: maps, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

here I am trying to rename branch name on the map this is what actual data is

```
%BRANCH_CODE_Key    Lat       Long


OHL BXHFP          25.3463  55.4209
Fujayr       
Neutral Zone         
Ras Al Khaymah       
CJYFL YAMPU        25.2048  55.2708
Umm Al Qaywayn       
NBQFF               24.4539 54.3773
```

now I want to rename OHL BXHFP into Sharjah and CJYFL YAMPU into Dubai and this NBQFF into Abu Dhabi

this column is linked to another table so I don't want to direct rename into table I want to rename these into map or any other condition may accepted but not directly into table this is what map looks like

and here I want names which I mentioned

this is the image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new column named "**Updated Branch Code**" using DAX and only rename these values. 
You can then use the **Updated Branch Code** column in the map visual.

The DAX Expression would be:

```
Updated Branch Code =
IF ( 'Table_Name'[%BRANCH_CODE_Key] = "OHL BXHFP", "Sharjah",
    IF ( 'Table_Name'[%BRANCH_CODE_Key] = "CJYFL YAMPU", "Dubai",
        IF ( 'Table_Name'[%BRANCH_CODE_Key] = "NBQFF", "Abu Dhabi", [%BRANCH_CODE_Key] )
       )
   )
```

Or You can use the Switch function as well like below:

```
Updated Branch Code =
SWITCH (
    'Table_Name'[%BRANCH_CODE_Key],
    "OHL BXHFP", "Sharjah",
    "CJYFL YAMPU", "Dubai",
    "NBQFF", "Abu Dhabi",
    'Table_Name'[%BRANCH_CODE_Key]
)
```

**Note:** Replace Table_Name with your actual table/query name

Comment: this shows an error " Can not find  name [%BRANCH_CODE_Key]

Comment: you can simply start typing the column name of branch code, it will be shown as a drop-down which you can select. It should be "**'Table_Name'[Column_Name]**". Your image doesn't show the table name, but you can find it just by typing.